Is there a way to have GeoServer store it's configuration in a database instead of XML files
Is there a way to have GeoServer store it's configuration in a database instead of XML files?
The reason for this is that we control GeoServer using its REST interface and we want the GeoServer configuration to sit in the same database as the rest of the application. Which makes backup and recovery a lot easier.

Yes, you can install the JDBCConfig extension:

It allows externalising the storage of the Catalog configuration objects (such as workspaces, stores, layers) to a Relational Database Management System, rather than using xml files in the GeoServer data directory. This way the Catalog can support access to unlimited numbers of those configuration objects efficiently.

You should note that it is a community module so not actively supported but I'm sure if you are running a mission critical part of your business based on it you'll have a budget that can support the maintainers.
